# Flex secure logon fails when running deployed application

Tags: java, apache-flex, security, https, blazeds

I have a Flex application and am having issues with secure logon / logoff to my Java server application. It works fine in the development environment (FlashBuilder running the Flex and communicating with Apache Tomcat) but fails when we try to use the exported flex application when deployed on the same Tomcat.

We have a large, complex application with a Flex front-end and a Java back-end which runs as a Web Application on Tomcat.
We want the login / logout process to use HTTPS so that the username and password are encrypted and aren't subject to certain security issues.

The way that unsecured login works is via a BlazeDS RPC call to a method called login. The user's credentials as parameters to the method.
*(Quick aside: is this the recommended way of performing a login?)*

Secure login works differently. A token is created from a channelSet which is supplied with the userid and password and an AsyncResponder calls the success or failure function. The login code is shown in update #2 below.

When I run my application in Flash Builder against an Apache Tomcat (ver 7.0.29) secure login and logout succeed. This works regardless of if I am in standard run or debug mode.

However once I create my application and deploy it to my server then it fails with a very generic error.

I am convinced I have setup the HTTPS side of Tomcat correctly (since the application works in the development environment). I believe that the issue lies in when the Flex application is running from `file:///...index.html` it works but as soon as I try to run it from `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/` it fails.

I have been pulling my hair out over this for days. Any pointers, documentation, etc. that anyone can give will be gratefully appreciated.

I decided not to include services-config.xml, remoting-config.xml, etc. files in this question since they are large and contain more than is relevant here, but I can supply them on request.

**Update: 1**

After reviewing the code I released I'd made an error in this question. The login RPC method is used for unsecure login attempts, whilst logging in via a mx.messaging.ChannelSet is used for secure login. I've updated the question to reflect this.

**Update: 2**

The error returned is an `mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent` which has the fields:

```
Fault String: Send failed
Fault Code: Client.Error.MessageSend
```

The logon function (Flex side) is:

```
public function login(username:String, password:String, loginFunction:Function = null, failureFunction:Function = null):void {
    if (_usingSecuredConnection) {
        this.loginSuccessFunction = loginFunction;
        this.loginFailureFunction = failureFunction;

        // Make sure that the user is not already logged in.
        if (_channelSet.authenticated == true) {
            AlertUtil.alertError("You are already logged in!");
            return;
        }

        token = _channelSet.login(username, password);
        token.addResponder(new AsyncResponder(loginResultEvent, loginFaultEvent));
    } else {
        // Defer to API
    SecurityAPI.login(username, password, [onLoginResultNonSecured, loginFunction], [onLoginFailure, failureFunction]);
    }
}
```

On an attempt to login securely, it always results in the function loginFaultEvent being invoked invoked with the FaultEvent as stated above.

**Update 3**

I am convinced that this is now a crossdomain issue. Trying to access https from http is the problem. However I have put what I think is a VERY permissive crossdomain file in the ROOT webapp of my Tomcat server and it has not helped. Anyone know what I am doing wrong? Is it the wrong location for Tomcat7 or have I got a mistake in my crossdomain file? (note: 8443 is my secure port)

**crossdomain.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all" />
    <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" to-ports="8443"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="localhost" headers="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

**Update 4**

I have now overcome this issue: It was a crossdomain problem and was fixed by placing a cross-domain file in the ROOT webapp directory of my tomcat server. The content of that cross-domain file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

My flex application now communicates HTTP and HTTPS fine using IE9 and Chrome.

However it still doesn't work on Firefox.

Thanks,

Phil

Comment: What is that 'very generic' error saying? I assume you ran your exported app in a debug version of the Flash Player, so you get all the thrown exceptions, right?

Comment: I'll ask if, in your development environment, you are running the app from a web server or from the file system?  If the latter; are you SWF and login service on the same server?  If not; is a cross domain file in place?

Comment: @www.Flexras.com The app is run from the Tomcat web-server. The user requests the app from the fileserver. I do have a cross domain file and I believe it is at it's most lenient . The contents of this file are (sorry about the formatting): 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-d
omain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>

Comment: @Cristi Mihai  I am using the debug version of Flash but the error isn't thrown at the browser level. The error that is returned is a mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent which is picked up by the code. FaultEvent has a faultCode and a faultString neither of which are very helpful. I'll update the question with these values as soon as I've got them.